# Selection is not working properly

Tags: css

`::selection{}` does not work everywhere. I need it to work everywhere.

I've tried

```
::selection,
p::-moz-selection, input::-moz-selection, textarea::-moz-selection,
p::-webkit-selection, input::-webkit-selection, textarea::-webkit-selection,
p::-o-selection, input::-o-selection, textarea::-o-selection,
p::-ms-selection, input::-ms-selection, textarea::-ms-selection,
p::selection, input::selection, textarea::selection
{
    background: red;
}
```

but it doesn't work. I keep getting results like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XwwRJ/)

[image]

I need this to just work without having to worry about random mysterious unsolvable problems. Is there a magic csv selector that will make all of my problems go away?

Comment: I don't really think that's possible with pure CSS... and if it is, then it probably only works in a few browsers.

Comment: "Is there a magic csv[sic] selector that will make all of my problems go away?" That's a pretty big thing to ask for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## From the [MDN][1]:

> **Non-standard:** This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards
>   track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not
>   work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
>   implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

### Specifications

The ::selection CSS pseudo-element was drafted for CSS Selectors Level 3 but removed before it reached the Recommendation status. Despite this, it's implemented in some browsers, which will probably retain experimental support for it.

Right now, the ::selection CSS pseudo-element is not in any specification on the standard track.

### Support

[image]

More can be found [@MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection).

Comment: What should I do then? Just allow the blue (or orange in Ubuntu, etc)?

Comment: @user1873073 you could still use this feature as an embellishment for newer browsers, but be careful don't make this crucial to you're website as this property might change in the future.

Comment: thanks for the help. i guess i will just support it the best i can.